# Installing AutoCAD through WineHQ

Tags: 16.04, wine

I'm working with Ubuntu 16.04 and I installed the latest version of WineHQ. I want to install AutoCAD but I don't know how. Any thoughts?

Comment: Basically forget it. Recent versions of autocad [does not work in wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/appview.php?iAppId=86). You can get ancient versions to work. Install a virtualization-solution and install autocad in a virtual windows machine.

Comment: everytime i have started to vm it's installing win7 all over again. it's litterally pissing me off. also network problem appears

Comment: Remove the CD from the virtual drive after installing. And use bridge mode networking

Comment: when i remove cd then windows issues appear

Comment: I use QCAD & I even prefer it to AutoCAD

Comment: @vidarlo I guess "you can't" is the answer...

Comment: I voted to leave this question open. Wine is on topic and as the other people, some Ubuntu users (as me) want to use the most popular CAD/CAM software packages on their primary OS. It is worth to know this is possible or not. @vidarlo, I'm asking you to convert your first comment into an answer :)

Comment: @pa4080 I agree with you. And posted as answer

Answer (score 2):

Basically forget it. Recent versions of Autocad does [not work in wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/appview.php?iAppId=86).

You can get ancient versions to work, by what WineHQ has to say about the state of the software.

If you need Autocad, and are unwilling to boot Windows, install a virtualization-solution and install autocad in a virtual windows machine.